# Save or cache selected columns by columnChooser on devextreme DataGrid

Tags: c#, angularjs, datagridview, devexpress, devextreme

How can i save or cache selected columns in devextreme datagrid for each user? by cookie, session, in database or anything else...!
the problem is users select what they want or need but by page reloading everything   will reset!

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Good answer! I found an attribute named stateStoring on their documentations that do localStorage's job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to grid Config:

```
stateStoring: {
   enabled: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Angular Js`, you need add this code to config as below

```
stateStoring: {
     enabled: true
}
```

If you store data in localStorage

```
stateStoring: {
     enabled: true,
     type: "localStorage",
     storageKey: "storage"//This is localStorage's item key
}
```

For more information, please visit this link   [Devextreme Datagrid State Persistence in Angular Js](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/StatePersistence/AngularJS/Light/)

If you use `Angular 2+`, you can use `dxo-state-storing` component.For more information, please visit this link : [Devextreme Datagrid State Persistence in Angular 2+](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/StatePersistence/Angular/Light/)